# Updating Office 365 attributes and creating new accounts using Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm working on a powershell script that will do the following:

1. Will log into our O365 instance
2. Read the CSV file and update the users attributes (such as department and title)
3. If the user isn't found, create a new one with those attributes.

If i comment out the New-AzureADUser section it will work fine and update the users that are found, but when i do call New-AzureADUser i get the following error.

```
New-AzureADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'DisplayName'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I understand the meaning behind the error in that it wants a string, not an object but i'm a little unsure on next steps.

```
# Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

# Get CSV content
$CSVrecords = Import-Csv bra_o365_import1.csv -Delimiter ","
#CSV contains UserPrincipalName,Department,DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,Title

# Loop trough CSV records
foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
    $upn = $CSVrecord.UserPrincipalName
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"  
    if ($user) {
        try{
        $user | Set-AzureADUser -Department $CSVrecord.Department -JobTitle $CSVrecord.Title
        } catch {
        
        Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update."
        }
    }
    else {

    New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $CSVrecords.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $CSVrecords.UserPrincipalName -AccountEnabled $true -Department $CSVrecord.Department -JobTitle $CSVrecord.Title

    Write-Host  $CSVrecords.DisplayName
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `$CSVrecord`, not `$CSVrecords`

Comment: well....... that is embarrassing!

Comment: Understandable because your variable names are quite similar. Better use an iteration variable like `$item` or `$row` to distinguish it more from the collection itself.